Flutter - Install an application on a iPhone without using testflight or USB cable
While developing iOS applications with flutter, I install the app on an iPhone by connecting to it via USB and running the project in profile mode. Installing the app by this way is inconvenient and impossible when the testing team is not present at the same location as the developer.
I share the android build as an .apk file. Is there a similar way to share the ios app over the internet?

I followed this one, and it worked.
Similar Question

Upload your .ipa to https://www.diawi.com, It will give you a
download link. In this approach, you have to add the devices UDI to
your developer account devices


That works, but sending my application to a third party service seems insecure. Is there an official apple solution for this though?

isn't the Testflight official solution? There is no certain threat using this third-party way as you will use the app for testing.

I use TestFlight for beta users (production flavour). It cannot be used for testing, as the app ID of my testing and production flavours is different, and AppStore won't allow uploading it.

If you are using macOS and you want to build your app, use:

flutter build ios --release

You will find the app in your project's build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app

Is it possible to install the .app or .ipa If the testing team has just an iphone?
